# Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported

Tags: time, ntp

Mu Ubuntu 20.04 suffers from time synchronisation problems. Particularly:

```
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Sat 2021-05-01 09:30:44 EEST
           Universal time: Sat 2021-05-01 06:30:44 UTC 
                 RTC time: Fri 2021-04-30 16:05:23     
                Time zone: Europe/Riga (EEST, +0300)   
System clock synchronized: no                          
              NTP service: n/a                         
          RTC in local TZ: no                          
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
[sudo] password for v: 
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported
```

What could I debug?

```
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy ntp chrony openntpd
ntp:
  Installed: 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1
  Candidate: 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1 500
        500 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4 500
        500 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
chrony:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5-6ubuntu6.2
  Version table:
     3.5-6ubuntu6.2 500
        500 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.5-6ubuntu6 500
        500 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
openntpd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:6.2p3-4
  Version table:
     1:6.2p3-4 500
        500 http://lv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ 
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ dpkg -l ntp chrony openntpd
dpkg-query: no packages found matching chrony
dpkg-query: no packages found matching openntpd
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version                          Architecture Description
+++-==============-================================-============-==============>
ii  ntp            1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1 amd64        Network Time P>
lines 1-6/6 (END)
```

Comment: In the default config this service will provide time-sync
`systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service`
if it is active you'll get more info via
`timedatectl timesync-status`
If you just want to try "something else" you could install chrony which can not
only be a NTP server but also (by default) is an NTP client syncing you.
There you'd get status into via `systemctl status chrony` and `chronyc sources`.
Please provide that output if it needs further discusson - or if one of that led to the solution consider answering the question with what worked here?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service

Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.` `timedatectl timesync-status
Failed to query server: The name org.freedesktop.timesync1 was not provided by any .service files`

Comment: Hmm, if you install alternative (to the default systemd-timesyncd) NTP packages then the `systemd-timesyncd` will be removed - if you now happened to also `purge` the package then you'd be missing it and see that. In your case before anyone can help the question is which NTP do you have installed. What do the following show `apt-cache policy ntp chrony openntpd` and `dpkg -l ntp chrony openntpd` (add the output to your question for readability). FYI default is `systemd-timesynd` and if you want more features or a server then `chrony` - so I'd recommend to install either of those.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt added to question

Comment: Thanks, ok you have ntp (which is no more recommended in 20.04) and none of the others. Not sure what is wrong with your ntp (daemon) right now, but I'd recommend that you "apt purge ntp" and either "apt install chrony" OR "apt install systemd-timesyncd" - that should give you back proper ntp-sync.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, do I have to do additional steps to start the chrony service/synchronise?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, it seems `chrony` does not work with Kerberos authentification which forces me to think about reverting to ntp

Comment: No additional steps needed to activate it - if needed configuration is done via /etc/chrony/* . I understand why kerberos would need good time (and thereby some NTP implementation), but I don't see how ntp would "work with kerberos auth"  or not - could you describe that, maybe it is something that can be enabled or at least requested from chrony?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, yes it could be requested from `chrony`. There is also an incompatibility with `ssh`.

Comment: But could you elaborate what these incompatibilities with ssh and kerberos are exactly. I haven't heard from them and if true would like to know them at least properly filed/documented if not fixed. Especially before 22.04 is around. So if you could say more than "there is an incompatibility"  and "does not work with" about it I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, After a reboot of my OS I see that `chrony` works with Kerberos and `ssh`. I will observe and report if I encounter any problems.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, I reported a problem in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338889/chrony-clock-skew-too-great