# chrony; clock skew too great

Tags: ssh, ntp

I have a fully operational chrony on my Ubuntu:

```
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2021-05-17 17:02:03 EEST
           Universal time: Mon 2021-05-17 14:02:03 UTC 
                 RTC time: Mon 2021-05-17 14:02:04     
                Time zone: Europe/Riga (EEST, +0300)   
System clock synchronized: yes                         
              NTP service: active                      
          RTC in local TZ: no                          
v@v-VirtualBox:~$ systemctl status chrony
● chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrony.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-05-17 09:58:14 EEST; 7h ago
       Docs: man:chronyd(8)
             man:chronyc(1)
             man:chrony.conf(5)
    Process: 778 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/chronyd-starter.sh $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 807 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/chrony/chrony-helper update-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 802 (chronyd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 6897)
     Memory: 1.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/chrony.service
             ├─802 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F -1
             └─806 /usr/sbin/chronyd -F -1

May 17 10:22:21 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 78.194.78.49
May 17 10:23:22 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Source 91.189.89.198 replaced with 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8
May 17 10:27:41 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 91.189.89.199
May 17 10:27:41 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: System clock wrong by 1119.071625 seconds, adjustment started
May 17 10:29:51 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 162.159.200.123
May 17 10:53:36 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Source 2001:67c:1560:8003::c8 replaced with 91.189.89.198
May 17 14:49:46 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 78.194.78.49
May 17 14:52:57 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Source 162.159.200.123 replaced with 151.80.168.4
May 17 15:16:23 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 91.189.89.199
May 17 15:24:59 v-VirtualBox chronyd[802]: Selected source 78.194.78.49

v@v-VirtualBox:~$ chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 8
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^+ chilipepper.canonical.com     2   8   357   254  -2968us[-2968us] +/-   40ms
^+ pugot.canonical.com           2   9   357   991  +3907us[+3299us] +/-   41ms
^+ golem.canonical.com           2  10   377   26m   -883us[-1393us] +/-   59ms
^- alphyn.canonical.com          2   9   277   26m   -897us[-1399us] +/-   92ms
^+ 183-150-172-163.instance>     4   9   377   648  +2008us[+2008us] +/-   74ms
^+ net1.web.yas-online.net       3  10   377   514   +488us[ +488us] +/-   75ms
^* moz75-1-78-194-78-49.fbx>     3   9   377   664  +1298us[ +635us] +/-   30ms
^+ x.ns.gin.ntt.net              2   9   377  1169  -2448us[-3025us] +/-   73ms
```

However, when doing `ssh` with valid `Kerberos` tickets there is a clock skew problem:

```
ssh -Xvvv ***@**.**
...
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Clock skew too great
...
```

What is possibly wrong?

Comment: Do you know if the login target and the kerberos infrastructure synchronized to the same servers? If not that might explain your skew.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, no not the same servers. As a side note, I note that the clock skew problem this morning has disappeared without a reboot of my OS.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, today the problem is back

Comment: Hmm ... if client & server are in sync and happy - then all I can think of right now is that the NTP servers disagree so much that this gets into the skew problem. That is why I asked if they sync to the same (which usually all elements belonging to a network should). Any chance to configure them to sync to the same NTP?

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, I have submitted now a request to them.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, has a significant difference between NTP servers been confirmed in practice?

Comment: Yeah @Viesturs I've had other cases due to the same conceptual setup, AFAIK all solved by conceptually enforcing that all in the same "auth domain" are synced to the same servers. Actually IIRC they mostly created a local NTP linked to an upstream one and then synced all their devices to this local server.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, I notice that the clock skew problem disappears after a reboot. Is there some special synchronisation done during the reboot?

Comment: Yes, almost all time syncing mechanisms (systemd-timesyncd, ntp, chrony) are allowed to do a major jump once at the start of the system and only drift from there (a lot of details, but at this level that is the best summary I can give).